# ie9 ajax cross domain withCredentials not sending cookie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies, internet-explorer-9, cross-domain

I want to make a cross domain xhr with jquery ajax
I am using a special library that allows ie9 to support cross domain 
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajaxtransport-xdomainrequest/1.0.0/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js

the browser sends the xhr but without cookies (Credentials)
the following code runs at http://first_domain.local

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  crossDomain: true,
  data: {},
  dataType: 'json',
  xhrFields: {
   withCredentials: true
  }
});

jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  async: true,
  crossDomain: true,
  url: "http://second_domain.local",
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.withCredentials=true;
  },
  type: "POST",
  data: {},
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function(res, textStatus, xhr) {
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
  }
});
```

settings on php sever:

```
$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$http_origin.'');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

it works perfectly in IE 10,11 friefox and chrome

[image: ie 9 screen debugger shot]
[image: ie 11 screen debugger shot]

**ANSWER:**

there seems to be 2 opinions on this matter:

1. this is not possible
2. use MoonScript lib

both are valid, because "there is no way to make a cross-domain ajax request in IE9 and older and send cookies."

BUT! MoonScript does the trick(somehow) and it works for me.

So I would suggest you try MoonScript

Answer (score 2):

1. Cross origin requests are only possible in IE9 and older via `XDomainRequest`, NOT via `XMLHttpRequest`.  The library you are using delegates to `XDomainRequest` in these browsers.
2. Credentialed cross-origin ajax requests are not possible in IE9 and older, as `XDomainRequest` doesn't support this (no support for `withCredentials`).

Answer (score 0):

There's a seemless solution to this if you're using jquery $.ajax
simply include "MoonScript" JQuery ajax-transport and you're set!
https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

Comment: This is _not_ a solution to the question, not sure why this has been marked as such. There is _no_ way to make a cross-domain ajax request in IE9 and older _and_ send cookies. No library can make this possible, as the library would have to use `XDomainRequest`, which does not permit cookies ([among other things](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx)) to be sent with requests.

Comment: read the info in the link, it works for me. "Implements automatic Cross Origin Resource Sharing support using the XDomainRequest object for IE8 and IE9 when using the $.ajax function in jQuery 1.5+."

Comment: Your question asks how to send cookies. This answer is not a solution to your actual question. Perhaps you should update your question then?